# jQuery scale function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some code which is supposed to make an image go smaller until it disappears from the screen. If I have the image in a `div` it will not work properly. If I take it out of the `div` it will work fine.

However I need it to work in a `div`. How can I fix this?

The code works fine if the `img` is not in a `div`, but when it is it screws up.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#thrid").show('fast').animate({
    top : '-=-300',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
        },
        {duration: 1000});
},2000);
```

CSS:

```
#thrid{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left: 592px;
    top: 160px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thrid">
    <img src="images/thrid.png" alt="thrid">
</div>
```

This is what it does with the `div`: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xMV5Q/3/

This is what I want it to do: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xMV5Q/1/

Comment: when you say that it is screwing up... what do you mean?  Can you make a jsfiddle to show what you're experiencing... or please post the html for context.

Comment: I will post css and html but i dont think it will do much and iam not sure how to explain it really but basically it will go down 300 px and then it will disappear but not the way its meant to and then it reapers again.

Comment: that's ok, it will still provide some context as to what you're looking to do.  I, or someone else, may be able to predict what you are trying to communicate. :)

Comment: Ok edited it and i added examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the img's width and height to 100%:

```
#city2 img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The image re-appears because the div overflow is still visible

```
#city2 {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example (http://jsfiddle.net/will_moore/g6fYT/) and it seems to work OK for me, even with the div.

I'm guessing you've got some styles associated with the div that are causing problems. I don't see what your -=-300 is doing. Don't you mean '-=300'?.